# How can I set a default value when incorrect/invalid input is entered in Unix?

Tags: unix

i want to set the value of **inputLineNumber** to 20. I tried checking if no value is given by user by **[[-z "$inputLineNumber"]]** and then setting the value by **inputLineNumber=20**. The code gives this message **./t.sh: [-z: not found** as message on the console. How to resolve this? Here's my full script as well.

```
#!/bin/sh
cat /dev/null>copy.txt
echo "Please enter the sentence you want to search:"
read "inputVar"
echo "Please enter the name of the file in which you want to search:"
read "inputFileName"
echo "Please enter the number of lines you want to copy:"
read "inputLineNumber"
[[-z "$inputLineNumber"]] || inputLineNumber=20
for N in `grep -n $inputVar $inputFileName | cut -d ":" -f1`
do
  LIMIT=`expr $N + $inputLineNumber`
  sed -n $N,${LIMIT}p $inputFileName >> copy.txt
  echo "-----------------------" >> copy.txt
done
cat copy.txt
```

---

Changed the script after suggestion from @Kevin. Now the error message **./t.sh: syntax error at line 11: `$' unexpected**

```
#!/bin/sh
truncate copy.txt
echo "Please enter the sentence you want to search:"
read inputVar
echo "Please enter the name of the file in which you want to search:"
read inputFileName
echo Please enter the number of lines you want to copy:
read inputLineNumber
[ -z "$inputLineNumber" ] || inputLineNumber=20

for N in $(grep -n $inputVar $inputFileName | cut -d ":" -f1)
do
  LIMIT=$((N+inputLineNumber))
  sed -n $N,${LIMIT}p $inputFileName >> copy.txt
  echo "-----------------------" >> copy.txt
done
cat copy.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line from:

```
[[-z "$inputLineNumber"]] || inputLineNumber=20
```

To this:

```
if [[ -z "$inputLineNumber" ]]; then
   inputLineNumber=20
fi
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Where to start...

You are running as `/bin/sh` but trying to use `[[`. `[[` is a bash command that `sh` does not recognize. Either change the shebang to `/bin/bash` (preferred) or use `[` instead.

You do not have a space between `[[-z`. That causes bash to read it as a command named `[[-z`, which clearly doesn't exist. You need `[[ -z $inputLineNumber ]]` (note the space at the end too). Quoting within `[[` doesn't matter, but if you change to `[` (see above), you will need to keep the quotes.

Your code says `[[-z` but your error says `[-z`. Pick one.

Use `$(...)` instead of `` `...` ``. The backticks are deprecated, and `$()` handles quoting appropriately.

You don't need to `cat /dev/null >copy.txt`, certainly not twice without writing to it in-between. Use `truncate copy.txt` or just plain `>copy.txt`.

You seem to have inconsistent quoting. Quote or escape (`\x`) anything with special characters (`` ~, `, !, #, $, &, *, ^, (), [], \, <, >, ?, ', ", ; ``) or whitespace and any variable that could have whitespace. You don't need to quote string literals with no special characters (e.g. `":"`).

Instead of `` LIMIT=`expr...` ``, use `limit=$((N+inputLineNumber))`.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable inputs on the whole script rather than just the issue in hand. Clearly as you may have guessed, I am pretty new to Unix(basically my first script :)). Changes I made--> 1)Changed **[[** to **[** 2) Quoting fixed now! 3) /dev/null replaced by truncate. 4)Yep, me too noticed the twice part as soon as I posted. Corrected it as soon as I could but you're quicker! :D Changes not made-->1)Space though before z was already there in my code.Though not sure how this got deleted while pasting here :(

Comment: Regarding the last **LIMIT** part. I changed that as well could you maybe clear a doubt or two on this? What's the puporse of this double bracket over here? How is taking taking the value of the variable without $(Is this the purpose of the double brackets)?

Comment: `$((...))` is just cleaner than `expr`, and yes, within them you don't need the sigil (`$`).

Comment: Thanks, this is quite useful. I will remember this :) But now it shows new error :(